# Cannot concatenate keywords from xml with php

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following problem:

I cannot concatenate all the keywords in one string. It returns an array... I am trying for hours but I haven't managed it.

Here is the code:

(the if condition is in a loop)

```
$keyword="";
$entry=0;

if ($index=="keywordterm){
            $kword=$arrObjData[$index]; // takes the value of keywordterm
            $kwords[$entry]=$kword;
            echo "keywords[$entry]: ".$kwords[$entry]."</br></br>";
            $keywordd.=$kwords[$entry]." | ";   
            $entry++;           
}
print_r($keywordd);
echo "Keywords: ".$keywordd."<br><br>";
```

RESULT IS:

```
keywords[1]: telecommunication computing

keywords[2]: multi-agent systems

keywords[3]: state estimation

keywords[4]: control engineering computing

keywords[5]: telecommunication control

keywords[6]: Matlab-Simulink platform

keywords[7]: networked multiagent systems

keywords[8]: information sharing

keywords[9]: multiple cooperative agents

keywords[10]: networked control system

Array ( )
Keywords: Array
```

I wanted something like this:

```
Keywords: telecommunication computing | multi-agent systems | state estimation.........
```

The XML code is as follows:

```
<keywordset keywordtype="Inspec">
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[computer aided manufacturing]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[semantic Web]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[factory automation]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[ontologies (artificial intelligence)]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[knowledge based systems]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[inference mechanisms]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
    </keywordset>
    <keywordset keywordtype="InspecFree">
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[reconfigurable manufacturing systems]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[semantic Web services]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[factory automation]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[ontologies]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[explicit semantics]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[logical reasoning]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[autonomous manufacturing orchestration]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[knowledge based systems]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
    </keywordset>
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for this loooong code..

All the code is this:

```
$keywordd="";
$entry=0;
$kwords=array();
$xmlUrl = "9424.xml"; // XML feed file/URL

$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);

$arrXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObj, $entry, $keywordd);

function objectsIntoArray(&$arrObjData, &$entry, &$keywordd, $arrSkipIndices = array()) {

if (is_array($arrObjData)) {

    echo "<pre>";

        //print_r($arrObjData);
        echo "</pre>";  

        foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value) {

if ($index=="keywordterm"&&$index!="0"){
            $kword=$arrObjData[$index];
            echo "<b>KEYWORD: </b>".$kword."</br></br>";
            $kwords[$entry]=$kword;
            echo "keywords[$entry]: ".$kwords[$entry]."</br></br>";
            $keywordd.=$kwords[$entry]." | ";
            //echo $keywordd."<br><br>";
            $entry++;
            //echo "entry: ".$entry."<br>";

        }
        elseif ($index=="joursec"&&$index!="0"){
            //print_r($keywordd);
            echo "<b>Keywords: </b>".$keywordd."<br><br>";
        }
}
}
```

Comment: i am not sure but use .(concatenation) operator before double quotes when echoing the result.

Comment: Can you post the surrounding loop? From your code, there's no reason `$keywordd` would be an array. It should be a string since you're concatenating onto it with `.=`.

Comment: I just put the code for all....

Comment: you have `foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value) {`, but in the code above I don't see where you set $arrObjData.

Comment: I call it with $xmlObj: $arrXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObj, $entry, $keywordd);

Answer (score 1):

Since $keywordd is a string as I see, you can't print it with print_r?
What happens if you do just "echo $keywordd" ?

You should use implode() to get the array into a string?

example:

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

Comment: well, I put the whole code above because i may have confused you.

Comment: you can use implode to get array into string and than echo it 
example:

[php]
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
[/php]

Comment: echo $keywordd results in: Array

Comment: see my edited answer as well as MrGlass's. use implode() and then print $comma_separated value (echo $comma_separated;)

Comment: the problem is that the array is empty... Thank you for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(" | ", $array);
```

Comment: Array is empty, as I see from print_r($keywordd); (which results in Array ( ))